# Pytorch: Tensordot with non-contracting position

Tags: pytorch

Given a tensor `x` of shape `(a, b, d)` and a tensor `y` of shape `(b, c, d)`. I want to perform a matrix-multiplication-like operation such that position 2 of `x` resp. `y` (of length `d`) is contracted.

However, I don't want position `1` of `x` resp. `0` of `y` (of length `b`) to be contracted. Instead, I want to iterate slice-wise over this position, such that the result has shape `(a, b, c)`.

I could implement this as follows, using `b` times the `torch.tensordot` operation and then stacking the results:

```
# random initialization
a = 3
b = 2
c = 5
d = 8
x = torch.randn(a, b, d)
y = torch.randn(b, c, d)

slice_results = []
for idx in range(b):
    x_slice = x[:, idx, :]
    y_slice = y[idx, :, :]
    slice_result = torch.tensordot(x_slice, y_slice, dims=([1], [1]))
    slice_results.append(slice_result)

result = torch.stack(slice_results, dim=1)
print(result.shape)  # (a, b, c)
```

However, I wonder whether there is a more efficient way to implement this, without explicitly constructing a Python list.

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
r2 = torch.tensordot(x, y,dims=([2], [2]))

result_ = torch.zeros((a, b, c))

result_[:,1,:] = r2[:,:,1,:][:,1,:]
result_[:,0,:] = r2[:,:,0,:][:,0,:]

result_-result
```

output:

```
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

the thing is, it is not faster, unless you increase a and b by a lot.

```
def no_loop_method(x,y):
    r2 = torch.tensordot(x, y,dims=([2], [2]))

    result_ = torch.zeros((a, b, c))

    result_[:,1,:] = r2[:,:,1,:][:,1,:]
    result_[:,0,:] = r2[:,:,0,:][:,0,:]

def with_loop_method(x,y):
    slice_results = []
    for idx in range(b):

        x_slice = x[:, idx, :]
        y_slice = y[idx, :, :]
        slice_result = torch.tensordot(x_slice, y_slice, dims=([1], [1]))
        slice_results.append(slice_result)

    result = torch.stack(slice_results, dim=1)

a = 3
b = 2
c = 5
d = 8
x = torch.randn(a, b, d)
y = torch.randn(b, c, d)

timeit with_loop_method(x,y)
```

this will result in:

36.7 µs ± 177 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

```
timeit no_loop_method(x,y)
```

while this, will result in:

37.6 µs ± 111 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

but if you increase a and b:

```
a = 3000
b = 200
c = 5
d = 8
x = torch.randn(a, b, d)
y = torch.randn(b, c, d)

timeit with_loop_method(x,y)
```

12.4 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
timeit no_loop_method(x,y)
```

525 ms ± 16.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Actually, my true values  are quite a bit higher: `a` is about `47000`, `b=5`, `c=839`, `d=768`. Your solution as well as that of Ivan (which is almost the same) are quite a bit slower, as you also measured (your `no_loop_method` takes longer). The reason is probably that when `r2` is computed as an intermediate step, it contains much more entries than needed, namely `b*b / b = b = 5` times as many.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply [`torch.tensordot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensordot.html) on the whole tensor along `dim=2` then only select its diagonal (from `dim=1` to `dim=2`) using a slice:

```
>>> torch.tensordot(x, y, dims=([b], [b]))[:,range(b), range(b),:]
```

Comment: The dims-part should be `dims=([2], [2])`, I guess. However, your implementation is not faster (see the post of Guinther Kovalski).